# Please tell me how to integrate blackberry and android into the same IDE.

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I am Using phoneGap as a environment to develop the code. So I need to know how to integrate blackberry and android into the same IDE(Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

android:
update site:

(eclipse 3.4)
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

(eclipse 3.5)
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

blackberry(update site):

(eclipse 3.4)
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate

(eclipse 3.5)
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java