# Interface in android same as Persistable in Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry

Which Interface in android is same as Persistable interface in Blackberry

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378149/please-tell-me-how-to-integrate-blackberry-and-androied-into-the-same-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if you're trying to have something that is similar to the `PersistentStore`. You can make your object Serializable and then store a String you create from it into the SharedPreferences.